# Python/SQL/Excel I have 12 datasets and I want to combine them to one representative set

Tags: python, sql, excel, statistics

I'm trying to create a predictive curve using 12 different datasets of empirical data. Essentially I want to write a function that passes 2 variables (Number of Applications, Days) and generates a predictive curve based on the 12 datasets that i have. The datasets all have 60 days and have Number of Applications from 500 to 100,000.

I'm not really sure of what the best approach would be, I was thinking maybe taking the average percentage of total applications at each day (ex: at day 1 on average there are 3% of total applications issued, day 10 on average there are 10%, etc)would be a good place to start but i'm not sure if that's the best approach.

I have python, SQL, and excel at my disposal but I'm not necessarily looking for a specific solution as much as just a general suggestion on approach. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Depends on what you're trying to predict and with what assumptions. At one extreme, you're trying to predict each separately, and each is generated by different and independent processes, in which case, do 12 different models. At the other extreme, you see them all as noisy measures of the same thing, which you're trying to predict, in which case, yes, a within-time-point average makes sense (ideally with each series weighted by its apparent reliability). The most complicated place to be is the middle ground between these extremes, where they're distinct but maybe even interacting processes.

Comment: @DHW each of the 12 is distinct, they just vary by location but at this stage we're just looking for something very basic so i think I will move forward with the averages. Would you consider the median or the average to be more representative? does it matter much?

Comment: This isn't my primary wheelhouse, but that sounds like time-series cross-sectional (TSCS) data, once you stack it into a 12x60 dataset.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to break it all out into (60*12) rows with 3 columns: one recording the application number, another recording the time, and another recording the location. Then a model could dummy out each location as a predictor, and you could generate 12 simulated predictions, with uncertainty. Then, to get your one overall prediction, average those predictions instead - bootstrap and then pool the predictions if you're fancy. Model time however you want - autoregression, Kalman filter, nearest-neighbor (probably not enough data for that one though). Just don't dummy out each time point individually or you'll have a perfect-fitting model.

But be aware of the possible universe of interactions between the locations that you could model here. Dummying them all out assumes no interactions between them, or at least one you care about, or that relate to anything you care about. It just accounts for fixed effects, i.e. you're assuming that the time dynamic within each location is the same, it's just that some locations tend overall and on average to have higher application numbers than others. You could derive tons of predictors pertaining to any given location based on the application number(s) in other location(s) - current number, past number, etc. All depends on what you consider to be possible and informative to account for.